# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_StudentCourses'. Cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm a beginner and trying to create a many to many relation using a post request to user

```
/ApplyCourse/?studentId=1003&courseId=3
```

but I get the following error:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_StudentCourses'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.StudentCourses'. The duplicate key value is (1003, 3).

What am I doing wrong? What is a good approach to create many to many relations?

```
[Route("CourseApply")]
[HttpPost("{studentId}/{courseId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CourseApply(int studentId, int courseId)
{
        Student studentEntity = _context.Students.Find(studentId);
        Course courseEntity = _context.Courses.Find(courseId);

        StudentCourse enrollment = new StudentCourse();
        enrollment.Course = courseEntity;
        enrollment.Student = studentEntity;

        _context.StudentCourses.Add(enrollment);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetStudent", new { id = studentEntity.Id }, studentEntity);
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<StudentCourse> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<StudentCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: StudentCourse doesn't have ID in the model; but I assume that there is some primary key in the database. Can you elaborate how it is defined in the `DbContext`?

Comment: I'm using a composite keys in OnModelCreating().

modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.StudentId, sc.CourseId });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key is composite: `StudentId, CourseId`. You already have combination of `StudentId = 1003; CourseId = 3` in the database; so you can't insert another row with the same values.

You need to decide whether you want to allow such duplicates - then create a separate key column (call it `Id` or `StudentCourseId` and entity framework will automatically use it as primary key). Or if you disallow duplicate combinations of Student / Course then you need to handle such error (for example, by redirecting the user to update existing record, rather than inserting a new one)

Personally, I try to avoid composite keys... but I guess, it's a matter of preference